# Создайте новую отсортированную строку, используя две строки со случайными символами в них. Строки содержат только буквы от a до z в powershell

Tags: строки, powershell

## Example :

```
$str1 = "xyaabbbccccdefww"

$str2 = "xxxxyyyyabklmopq"
```

## Result

```
"abcdefklmopqwxy"
```

Что я пробовал сделать? Сложил строки, добавил в массив, отсортировал и сделал уникальными, но как  результат обратно собрать в строку?

```
$str1 = "xyaabbbccccdefww"
$str2 = "xxxxyyyyabklmopq"

$a = $str1 + $str2

$b = $a.ToCharArray()

$b | Sort-Object -Unique
```

Comment: $b -join "" <-- так пробуйте или быстрее [String]::new($b)

Comment: Выдаёт результат a
b
c
d
e
f
k
l
m
o
p
q
w
x
y
xyaabbbccccdefwwxxxxyyyyabklmopq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял, строки д.б. случайными:

```
$str1 = -join ((97..122) | Get-Random -Count 15 | % {[char]$_})
$str2 = -join ((97..122) | Get-Random -Count 15 | % {[char]$_})
$str3 = (($str1 + $str2).ToCharArray() | sort -Unique) -join ""
$str1 + " + " + $str2 + " -> " + $str3
```

```
nmgvupkfdqowhil + lmjvhxdwnesakqy -> adefghijklmnopqsuvwxy
```

Код для генерации случайных строк взят [отсюда](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/generate-random-letters-with-powershell/)

Comment: $str1 = "xyaabbbccccdefww"
$str2 = "xxxxyyyyabklmopq"

$str3 = (($str1 + $str2).ToCharArray() | sort -Unique) -join ""

$str3